# max(value) of multiple columns in hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

For instance

```
ID   dt_col_1    dt_col_2    dt_col_3  
1    09-10-2018  08-10-2018  10-10-2018  
1    10-10-2018  null        11-10-2018  
1    11-10-2018  10-10-2018  12-10-2018  
2    null        08-10-2018  12-10-2018  
2    10-10-2018  13-10-2018  09-10-2018
```

looking for:

```
ID   dt_col_1    dt_col_2    dt_col_3  
1    null        null        12-10-2018  
2    null        13-10-2018  null
```

There is a greatest function in hive which returns greatest of multiple columns from one row but how can I apply the same in case of multiple rows as in example above?

Answer (score 0):

First apply group by to get max date for each id and then greatest function if you need seperate column or use case function.

```
create table test_stackof_greatest (id int, dt1 date, dt2 date, d3 date) row format delimited fields terminated by '\t' lines terminated by '\n' stored as textfile;

insert into test_stackof_greatest values (1, '2018-10-09', '2018-10-08', '2018-10-10');
insert into test_stackof_gereatest values (1, '2018-10-10', null, '2018-10-11'), (1, '2018-11-10', '2018-10-10', '2018-10-12');
 insert into test_stackof_gereatest values (2, null, '2018-10-08', '2018-10-12'), (2, '2018-10-10', '2018-10-13', '2018-10-09');

select id, case when dt1>dt2 and dt1>dt3 then dt1 else null end, case when dt2>dt1 and dt2>dt3 then dt2 else null end, case when dt3>dt2 and dt3>dt1 then dt3 else null end, greatest(dt1, dt2, dt3) from (select id, max(dt1) as dt1, max(dt2) as dt2, max(d3) as dt3 from test_stackof_gereatest group by id) a;

Output
OK
1       2018-11-10      NULL    NULL    2018-11-10
2       NULL    2018-10-13      NULL    2018-10-13
Time taken: 20.467 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
```

Hope this helps